# Is the array empty?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist, tostring

So I'm trying to figure out a possible source of a ArrayOutOfBoundException error in my code.

The purpose of the code is to print a pile of cards to a notepad file like so:

```
public void printCardPiles (PrintWriter writer)
{
  writer.println("Piles: ");

  for (int i = 0; i < piles.size(); i++)      

    {

       writer.println();
       MyArrayList<Card> tester = piles.get(i).getList();    

       writer.print(tester.toString());


    }

}
```

The issue is I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but I can't quite figure out where the source is coming from.

I've noticed even if I change to the code to:

```
public void printCardPiles (PrintWriter writer)
{
  writer.println("Piles: ");

  for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) // CHANGE: i < piles.size() to i < 1
    {

       writer.println();
       MyArrayList<Card> tester = piles.get(i).getList();


       writer.print(tester.toString());


    }

}
```

I'm still getting the out of bounds exception no matter what.

The exception points to the line `writer.print(tester.toString());` so could that be the source? The exact exception is as follows (with comments added for context):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at Card.toString(Card.java:134)                          // Sets up a card object      
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at MyArrayList.toString(MyArrayList.java:168)
at Table.printCardPiles(Table.java:199)                  // The exception location
at SortCardGame.playGame(SortCardGame.java:113)          // Where the exception's method is being called from 
at SortCardGame.main(SortCardGame.java:52)
```

Does this mean that the code is being using an empty array (in this case that empty array would be piles). which causes the exception? Or is it something else?

Note: The toString() for a card looks like this as well:

```
public String toString()
{
    String printString = RANKS[rank - 1] + SUITS[suit - 1];    // RANKS is the the array holding all the possible Ranks 
                                                               // rank is what rank the current card is
                                                               // Same as the above
    return printString;
}
```

I appreciate the help everyone, I know it's pretty vague but I can provide more detail as needed. I'm mainly looking for a few idea's on where to start looking for the problem, or what could be causing the problem.

*EDIT:* At request I'm adding the entirety of the Card Class.

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card>
{
// For printing the card rank

public static String[] RANKS =
{
    " A", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "10", " J", " Q", " K"
};

// For printing the card suit

public static String[] SUITS =
{
    "-C", "-D", "-H", "-S"
};

// private instance variables

private int rank;
private int suit;

// Default Constructor: initialize to Ace of Clubs

public Card()
{
    rank = 1;
    suit = 1;
}

// Two-Param Constructor : initialize rank and suit

public Card (int initRank, int initSuit)
{
    rank = initRank;
    suit = initSuit;
}

// Copy constructor: Copies a Card from another Card

public Card (Card otherCard)
{
    otherCard.rank = rank;
    otherCard.suit = suit;
}

// Returns relative position of this Card to someCard.
// This compares the Cards, first by rank: Aces low, King High
// then Suit within rank: CLUB=1, DIAMOND=2, HEART=3, SPADE=4

public int compareTo (Card someCard)
{
    if (rank > someCard.rank)
    {
        if (suit > someCard.rank)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (suit < someCard.rank)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if (rank < someCard.rank)
    {
        if (suit > someCard.rank)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (suit < someCard.rank)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (suit > someCard.rank)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (suit < someCard.rank)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }



}



// Determines whether this Card has the same rank and suit
// as another Card passed in - Note cast of obj to Card

@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj)
{
    Card someCard = (Card) obj;
    return (someCard.compareTo (this) == 0);
}

// Print the card's rank and suit using the static
// String arrays defined about

public String toString()
{
    String printString = RANKS[rank - 1] + SUITS[suit - 1];
    return printString;
}
```

}

A quick note, I **did not** write the equals() or toString() of the Card Class.

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace of the error

Comment: If `rank` (*and/or* `suit`) is `0` then you would get that exception (what values do they have?)

Comment: post your detail `Card` class please

Comment: Addressed your comments in the main post, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Let's debug and check what the value of `rank` and `suit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem you are using the copy constructor. The issue makes the instance will have `rank` & `suit` is 0. This makes `toString` work incorrectly

```
public Card (Card otherCard)
{
    otherCard.rank = rank;
    otherCard.suit = suit;
}
```

This should be

```
public Card (Card otherCard)
{
    this.rank = otherCard.rank;
    this.suit = otherCard.suit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the exception is occuring because of this line

```
String printString = RANKS[rank - 1] + SUITS[suit - 1];
```

Please make sure that the value of `rank-1` and `suit-1`are greater than or equal to 0.
rank>=1 and suit>=1